# Why does gfortran depend on the position of lblas flag?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, blas

I can compile a Fortran code using

```sh
gfortran -o $target *.o -lblas
```

But it does not compile with

```sh
gfortran -lblas -o $target *.o
```

Why does it depend on the position of the `-lblas` flag? Is it the standard behavior? If not, how can I troubleshoot?

The `BLAS` libraries are in a non-standard location and set in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables. Running `gfortran v9.3.0` on `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Comment: This is common for all languages in GCC, and most other compilers (and linkers) also. A library is only recognized as needed, and thus linked, if it it is looked at, which occurs in the order given on the commandline, _after_ the (or at least one) object module that references it. Although this practice is very common, there is no _de jure_ standard on this topic that I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. That was what I was looking for.